# Problems installing kong's UI KongDash (I can't see the Dashboard after installation)

Tags: user-interface, kong

I installed [KongDash](https://github.com/ajaysreedhar/kongdash) which is the UI for [Kong](https://getkong.org/) on one of my VirtualBox instances using CentOS 7. I'm trying to see the UI installed after following the installation steps.

In my case I downloaded the .tar.gz file, extracted the file and then execute the install.sh file. It's not clear how you can see the dashboard after you install the UI, so what I did is I went to the browser and try to open 127.0.0.1:8001 and port 8000 like with other UIs e.g. [Konga](https://github.com/pantsel/konga) which has clearer instructions on how to install it.

When I opened that URL I only see JSON-like code in my browser, eg.:

```
{"request_path":"\/","message":"API not found with these values" ......
```

If someone has installed this UI, I would appreciate they could give me a hand on this.

Answer (score 0):

KongDash is a standalone application and doesn't run inside a browser.
Seems like you have kong installed in centOS inside a virtual box. If your host machine is Windows, then you can directly install and run from .exe installer. Just run the kongdash app and in settings give 'Host' url to the ip of your virtual box instance eg. 192.xx.xxx.xx:8001